# Sql - Fetch next value to replace variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Hi guys my basic sql knowledge needs some help

I want to be able to replace a variable value with a value in a table and keep running the query until the end value in the table is reached

start query

```
DECLARE @prime_SCHEMA VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @next_SCHEMA VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @TABLE_name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)

SET @prime_SCHEMA = 'aaa'
SET @next_SCHEMA = 'bbb'
SET @TABLE = 'table1' 
SET @sql = 'select top 1 * into '+@next_SCHEMA +'.'+@TABLE_name +' from '+@prime_SCHEMA +'.'+@TABLE_name +' TRUNCATE TABLE '+@next_SCHEMA +'.'+@TABLE_name 
print @sql
```

I now want to wrap this in a Fetch and use a table called 'table_val' to update the TABLE_name value 
and loop around till all the rows have been used in the table

so effectively i could end up with multiple @sql statements

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @prime_schema SYSNAME = 'aaa'
    , @next_schema SYSNAME = 'bbb'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT CHAR(13) + '
        SELECT * 
        INTO [' + @next_schema + '].[' + o.name + ']
        FROM [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']
        WHERE 1 != 1'
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND s.name = @prime_schema
        AND o.name IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT * 
INTO [bbb].[table1]
FROM [aaa].[table1]
WHERE 1 != 1

SELECT * 
INTO [bbb].[table2]
FROM [aaa].[table2]
WHERE 1 != 1

SELECT * 
INTO [bbb].[table3]
FROM [aaa].[table3]
WHERE 1 != 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt response 
I was more are multiple statements thank create the tables on the bbb schema. Then Truncate was just to clear the top 1

Comment: okay this works but how does will i replace the table name with table2,table3 and onward 
i'd use ssis for this usually but this needs to be done in sql

Comment: @user2181700, I am glad that I was helpful to you :)